# indentifier expected array in Pascal program?

Tags: arrays, pascal

problem of excuting a pascal program, the problem of program is not knowing the variable "array" when i compile it

```
procedure former(var V:array[1..6] of integer; N:integer);
var c,d,u:integer;
```

Comment: If you're getting a compiler error, you should include the *exact error message* you're getting in your question. It's right on the screen in front of you; there is absolutely no reason for you not to include it for us to see also. It's information about *your problem* that you're asking us to help you solve for free - you can at least give us the information you already have so we can use it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible in standard pascal, but I think you can do it like this:

```
TYPE vektor = ARRAY[1..6] OF INTEGER;

procedure former(var V:vektor; N:integer);
var c,d,u:integer;
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would accept my answer if this solved your problem (the check mark beside the answer).